# Program crashes when malloc executed

Tags: c, crash, buffer-overflow, callstack

My code keeps crashing when I execute `*arr = malloc(i * sizeof(struct cluster_t*));`. Cluster is a structure.
I am not sure what is the problem. The second input is an array of structures (clusters) It is supposed to load the txt file into the array, each line as a separate structure The first input is a .txt file containing This:

```
    count=20
40 86 663
43 747 938
47 285 973
49 548 422
52 741 541
56 44 854
57 795 59
61 267 375
62 85 874
66 125 211
68 80 770
72 277 272
74 222 444
75 28 603
79 926 463
83 603 68
86 238 650
87 149 304
89 749 190
93 944 835
```

Here is the part of code that seems to be faulty (I modified it a little after the first answer) This is not a complete code:

```
int load_clusters(char *filename, struct cluster_t **arr) //nefunkcne
{
    assert(arr != NULL);

    char buffer_load[256] = {'0'};
    int riadok = 0;
    int count = 0;

    int *X = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (X == NULL) {
        perror("Chyba mallocu na load_clusters X");
        free(X);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int *Y = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (Y == NULL) {
        perror("Chyba mallocu load_clusters Y");
        free(X);
        free(Y);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int *ID = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (ID == NULL) {
        perror("Chyba mallocu v load_clusters ID");
        free(X);
        free(Y);
        free(ID);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *subor = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (subor == NULL) {
        perror("Chyba nacitania suobru fopen load_clusters!");
    }

    while (fgets(buffer_load, sizeof buffer_load, subor) != NULL) {
        if (riadok > 0) {
            struct cluster_t shluk;
            sscanf(buffer_load,"%d %d %d", ID, X, Y);
            init_cluster(&shluk, 1);
            struct obj_t objekt;
            objekt.id = *ID;
            objekt.x = *X;
            objekt.y = *Y;

            append_cluster(&shluk, objekt);

            arr[riadok - 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct cluster_t*));
            if (arr[riadok-1] == NULL) {
                perror("Chyba mallocu v load_clusters 388!");
                free(arr[riadok - 1]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            (*arr)[riadok - 1] = shluk;
        } else {
            sscanf(buffer_load, "count=%d", &count);
            *arr = malloc(count * sizeof(struct cluster_t));
            if (arr == NULL) {
                perror("Chyba mallocu v load_clusters 400!");
                free(*arr);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        riadok++;
    }

    fclose(subor);
    free(X);
    free(Y);
    free(ID);
    return cout;
}
```

Full code I keep up to date (remember to use `-std=c99 -Wextra -Wall -Werror -DNDEBUG and also -lm if in gcc becuase of math library):
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xoNcBpY1lkmki3-E5WUYFVg-xojjvEkUJ63XC_UzhtM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130349/discussion-on-question-by-luk164-program-crashes-when-malloc-executed).

Comment: always good to show def of mentioned structures

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complicated and has problems:

- You do not need to allocate data to pass pointers to `scanf()`, just pass the addresses of local variables.
- Check the return value of `scanf()`: it returns the number of successful conversions. If a conversion failed, the corresponding variable is not set and the remaining conversions fail too.
- If your txt file starts with spaces such as `count=20`, the `scanf` format should include an initial space to consume these spaces: `" count=%d"`.
- There seems to be a lot of confusion between pointers and structures: should the function allocate an array of clusters or load a sequence of object into an allocated cluster?

Here is a simplified version that loads the objects into a single allocated cluster:

```
int load_clusters(const char *filename, struct cluster_t **arr) {
    char buffer_load[256];
    int riadok, count, X, Y, ID;
    struct cluster_t *cp;

    assert(arr != NULL);

    // Open the input file
    FILE *subor = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (subor == NULL) {
        perror("Chyba nacitania suobru fopen load_clusters!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Read and parse the count line
    if (fgets(buffer_load, sizeof buffer_load, subor) == NULL ||
        sscanf(buffer_load, " count=%d", &count) != 1) {
        perror("missing count line in file\n");
        fclose(subor);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // allocate and initialize the cluster
    *arr = cp = malloc(sizeof(**arr));
    if (cp == NULL) {
        perror("Chyba mallocu v load_clusters 400!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    init_cluster(cp, count);

    riadok = 0;
    while (riadok < count &&
           fgets(buffer_load, sizeof buffer_load, subor) != NULL) {
        if (sscanf(buffer_load,"%d %d %d", &ID, &X, &Y) == 3) {
            struct obj_t objekt;
            objekt.id = ID;
            objekt.x = X;
            objekt.y = Y;
            append_cluster(cp, objekt);
            riadok++;
        }
    }

    fclose(subor);
    return riadok;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code cleanly compiles, but will not link due to missing sub functions.

Caveat: I am unable to test the code, so am not 100percent sure it will work properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fopen(), fclose(), fgets()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc()
#include <assert.h> // assert()
#include <string.h> // strchr()

struct cluster_t
{
};

struct obj_t
{
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;
};

void init_cluster(struct cluster_t*, int );
void append_cluster(struct cluster_t*, struct obj_t*);

int load_clusters(char *filename, struct cluster_t **arr) //nefunkcne
{
    assert(arr != NULL);

    char buffer_load[256] = {'0'};
    int riadok = 0;
    int i = 0;

    int X;
    int Y;
    int ID;

    FILE *subor = NULL;
    if( NULL == (subor = fopen(filename, "r") ) )
    {
        perror("Chyba nacitania suobru fopen load_clusters!");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    // initialize for number of struct instances
    if( ! fgets( buffer_load, sizeof( buffer_load ), subor ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "unable to read first line from input file\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char *token = NULL;
    if( NULL == (token = strchr( buffer_load, '=' ) ) )
    {
        fclose( subor );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    else
    { // else delimeter found
        token++; // step past '='
        i = atoi( token );

        // allocate array of pointers to 'struct cluster_t'
        if( NULL == (*arr = malloc( (size_t)i * sizeof(struct cluster_t*) ) ) )
        {
            perror("Chyba mallocu v load_clusters 400!");
            fclose( subor );
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful
    }


    while( riadok < i && fgets( buffer_load, sizeof buffer_load, subor) )
    {
        struct cluster_t shluk;
        sscanf(buffer_load,"%d %d %d", &ID, &X, &Y);

        init_cluster(&shluk, 1);

        struct obj_t objekt;
        objekt.id = ID;
        objekt.x  = X;
        objekt.y  = Y;
        append_cluster(&shluk, &objekt);

        if( NULL == ( arr[riadok] = malloc(sizeof(struct cluster_t)) ) )
        {
            perror("Chyba mallocu v load_clusters 388!");
            fclose( subor );

            for( int j=0; j<riadok; j++ )
            {
                free(arr[j]);
            }

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        memcpy( arr[riadok], &shluk, sizeof( struct cluster_t ) );

        riadok++;
    }

    fclose(subor);

    return i;
}
```

Comment: I posted the full code, and also custom settings for gcc.